# Field Calculation Python acceleration of gravity?

Tags: python

In my problem i have a column DISTANCE and a column TIME and i want to calculate with python in field calculator how much time it needs to make that distance (for example 1000m) if you are moving with the acceleration of gravity.

Since the field calculator does not *natively* support the square root function, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Is it a downward direction? Gravity is 9.8 metres per second per second, there are formulas for working this out based on Newtonian physics (I did them in High School, late '80s) so I don't remember them exactly. So are you trying to find out how long (TIME) it would take to fall that DISTANCE (terminal velocity aside)? Is this homework or are you looking to find somewhere to base jump from? Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body

Comment: @PolyGeo please re-open the question.  It's actually quite relevant to the field calculator.

Comment: @nagytech it seems like pure Python to me.  Try typing `print sqrt(25)` into any IDE - I just tested IDLE and it says `NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined`.  Then try `import math` followed by `print math.sqrt(25)` to get your answer.  Using the Python parser of the Field Calculator allows `math.sqrt()` without needing to import the math module.

Comment: It's largely about how to use the field calculator, and seemingly from the perspective of someone with little experience.  The question has been re-worded to better reflect the situation.

Comment: I'm happy to see whether this question is on-topic discussed in Meta GIS SE.  The position that I am likely to take is that questions about using non-GIS Python libraries like `math` belong on [SO] even if the IDE or parser is provided within a GIS product.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson now i gave more attention at your last sentence,"find somewhere to base jump from". If i was looking for something like that do you have any suggestions for equations of base jump?

Comment: A base jump is a falling object, terminal velocity and wind resistance aside it's the same as dropping a brick. If you have a raster that has the focal difference of a DEM you can find how long it would take to fall and then make a decision whether that's long enough to open a parachute... then finding the location of places where the terrain (POSSIBLY, there's more factors than just distace) supports base jumping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is as follows:

```
t=\sqrt{2d/g} where g = 9.807
```

[image]

To add this to the field calculator you can either use a (python code block)[http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002m000000]:

```
sqrt(2 * distance / 9.807)
```

Or, in the field calculator directly (since it does not support square root function):

```
(2 * distance / 9.807) ** 0.5
```

Comment: That does sound vaguely familiar... too much alcohol since high school. Is it necessary to go to 3 decimals (4 significant digits)? the value of g is not a constant and changes slightly on altitude (where g = (m1 * m2) / sqr(d) if d increases g is less http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-3/Newton-s-Law-of-Universal-Gravitation) and local density of the ground see http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2007/05/070511-weird-gravity.html... still it's more than I could remember. +1 from me

Comment: @nagytech thank you for your answer, but sqrt is not supported in field calculator! any other suggestion?

Comment: Since `sqrt(n) == n^0.5`, then `n ** 0.5` will give you the square root of n.  (** is shorthand for power-of in the field calculator)

Comment: @kon.pet You can use a python code block to have access to the sqrt function.  I don't have my hands on a copy of ESRI, and it's been a long time, but you can find our more here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002m000000